# Chromedriver failing to launch or connect

Tags: google-chrome, watir-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Up until today, I have been using chromedriver to drive my watir-webdriver tests, and I have had no problems. My server still works and runs tests on the same version of the chromedriver and chrome.

I have tried updating to the latest chromedriver, which is the chromedriver 2 experimental build.  This fails due to what I can only assume are still bugs being worked out of it. 
I have also tried rolling back to the previous version of chromedriver with no success.

If anyone has any experience with this, I would really appreciate your expertise. I am sure it will turn out to be something simple I have overlooked.

gem versions:

```
watir-webdriver (0.6.2)
selenium-webdriver (2.29.0)
cucumber (1.2.1)
```

trace from the chromedriver below

```
Started ChromeDriver port=9517 version=26.0.1383.0
log=C:\Projects\oms_acceptance_tests\src\chromedriver.log
[6136:5300:0212/122320:ERROR:master_preferences.cc(110)] Failed to read master_preferences file at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\master_preferences. Falling back to default preferences.

[6136:5300:0212/122320:ERROR:gpu_info_collector_win.cc(82)] Can't retrieve a valid WinSAT assessment.
test\automation\proxy_launcher.cc(107): error: Value of: app_launched
Actual: 5
Expected: AUTOMATION_SUCCESS
Which is: 0
Error while awaiting automation ping from browser process

[0212/122321:ERROR:proxy_launcher.cc(556)] Failed to ConnectToRunningBrowser

[0212/122321:ERROR:automation_proxy.cc(319)] Channel error in AutomationProxy.
Unable to either launch or connect to Chrome. Please check that ChromeDriver is up-to-date. Using Chrome binary at: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)
```

Comment: I've seen this intermittently with the most recent build 26.0.1383 and Chrome 25.0.1364.172 m; but while it appears on one test others work fine.  Have not been able to replicate a consistent error though

Comment: are you sure your server has the same exact version of chrome as your workstation?   Most of the times I have seen something like this, it was due to chrome on my workstation silently upgrading, and I needed an updated version of chromedriver

Answer (score 4):

I would trying downloading newer version of [chromedriver](http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list). Worked for me when I experienced similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the gpu winsat error, try to update your display adapter.